# tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath: runs before ViewDidLoad?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am trying to display some arrays in a UITableViewController. I have a custom cell with a NIB. The problem I'm running into is my table rows try to populate before my arrays are loaded in my `ViewDidLoad` . Setting breakpoints show that my table rows are being created and then directly after my arrays are given values (which are set in my `ViewDidLoad`.

Can anyone tell me why the `tableView` method is running before the `ViewDidLoad`? What do I need to do to ensure my arrays are loaded before the table rows are populated?

Here is my `ViewDidLoad` :

```
   - (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSLog(@"go");
    PFQuery *getCartQuery = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"chwCart"];
    [getCartQuery whereKey:@"userId" equalTo:[PFUser currentUser].objectId];
    [getCartQuery whereKey:@"status" equalTo:@"open"];

    [getCartQuery getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock:^(PFObject *currentCartObject, NSError *error) {

        // NSLog([currentCartObject objectId]);

        currentCart = [currentCartObject objectForKey:@"cartContents"];

        dictFoodId = [currentCart valueForKey:@"foodId"];

        dictQty = [currentCart valueForKey:@"qty"];

    }];
    NSLog(@"Should be loaded");

        [self.tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"foodCell" bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"foodCell"];


    }
```

Here is my `tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:`

```
(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"foodCell";
    foodCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    if (cell == nil) {

        cell = [[foodCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    }

    cell.foodTitle.text = [dictQty objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];


    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it's because you are updating the array into block which is running into background and your delegates called, just simply reload your tableView into block completion

```
[getCartQuery getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock:^(PFObject *currentCartObject, NSError *error) {

        // NSLog([currentCartObject objectId]);

        currentCart = [currentCartObject objectForKey:@"cartContents"];

        dictFoodId = [currentCart valueForKey:@"foodId"];

        dictQty = [currentCart valueForKey:@"qty"];

        [self.tableView reloadData];

    }];
```

Answer (score 3):

You are using blocks which does the process in background so your tableview is created and the delegate methods are called first you just add this line of code to your viewdidload code which will again call tableview after arrays are loaded

```
**[self.tableView reloadData];**
```

so your code in viewdidLoad should look like this

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
NSLog(@"go");
PFQuery *getCartQuery = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"chwCart"];
[getCartQuery whereKey:@"userId" equalTo:[PFUser currentUser].objectId];
[getCartQuery whereKey:@"status" equalTo:@"open"];

[getCartQuery getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock:^(PFObject *currentCartObject, NSError *error) {

    // NSLog([currentCartObject objectId]);

    currentCart = [currentCartObject objectForKey:@"cartContents"];

    dictFoodId = [currentCart valueForKey:@"foodId"];

    dictQty = [currentCart valueForKey:@"qty"];
    [self.tableView reloadData];

}];
NSLog(@"Should be loaded");

    [self.tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"foodCell" bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"foodCell"];


}
```